# Visual Studio 2015 Community unit test not discovered

Tags: unit-testing, vs-community-edition

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015.  I have added a new unit test project to my current solution.  When I view the test explorer or click > test > run all, none of my test are discovered.  Can I do this with Community Edition?

I have tried deleting my temp folders and cache files.  I deleted an existing unit test project and created a new project.  None of this worked.

Help!

Comment: Any luck ? i have same issue

Comment: Which unit test framework are you using NUnit? MSTest?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.  It is what comes as a default in a UnitTest project.  I still can not get my unittests to run or even be visiable to the text explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue with Visual Studio 2015 Community running inside of Parallels with Windows 7 (on a Mac).  After trying everyone's suggestions from other posts, I realized that the issue was indeed having the project files stored on a mapped network drive.  To fix this I simply:

1) Used Windows Explorer to relocate the Visual Studio 2015 folder from the mapped Y: drive to the Parallels C: drive (the drive that Visual Studio was installed on)

2) In Visual Studio, updated the path for settings to the new location on the C drive:  Tools > Settings > Environment > Import and Export Settings

3) In Visual Studio, updated the locations where Projects and templates get stored:  Tools > Settings > Projects and Solutions

Once I relocated the Projects to the C: drive, my unit tests were discoverable.